# Allow normal user to run PHP script as root using SUDO

Tags: php, scripting, sudo, root, users

How can I allow a normal user on Ubuntu to run php scripts?

*sudo php /path/to/script/script.php*

Basically the script needs to be run as root but the users does not have root privileges on their machines.

I have seen articles that indicate that you need to add php to the sudoers file?

EDIT: Modified command as I wrote wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious usage of sudo is this:

```
sudo php /path/to/script/script.php
```

You have to put both the respective users and the php call into sudoers. It would be risky to allow php calls globally. Instead just the call to this specific script (which really should not be writable by users, the same for all parent directories).